# LiteDB Studio: Unexpected token {

Tags: litedb

I'm trying to use LiteDB Studio 1.0.2 to import a JSON file.  I've created a database and selected the menu option "**Import from JSON**".  I selected a sample file that I found in a post related to NoSQL.  It contains:

```
{
  "Contact": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "FullName": "Lucy",
      "Email": "lucy@gmail.com",
      "Phone": "4584656970",
      "Address": "223 Str"
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "FullName": "Tom",
      "Email": "tom@gmail.com",
      "Phone": "4375588889",
      "Address": "123 Str"
    }
  ]
}
```

The menu option produces a query template that I updated to:

```
SELECT $
  INTO new_col
  FROM $file('Sample.json');
```

Upon running the query, I immediately receive an error:

> Unexpected token `{` in position 0.
>
> SELECT $   INTO ^

Can anyone shed light on this error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that LiteDB expects an array of document, so your file should start by [ and end by ] and the documents inside { } in the middle

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However, I've given up on using LiteDB.

Answer (score 0):

LiteDB expects an array of json elements, so your file should look like this example

```
[
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "FullName": "fullname_1",
        "Email": "a@example1.com",
        "Phone": "0123456789",
        "Address": "123 Street"
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "FullName": "fullname_2",
        "Email": "fullname_2@example1.com",
        "Phone": "9876543210",
        "Address": "321 Street"
    }
]
```

and your Insert statement will be like that

```
SELECT $
  INTO contacts
  FROM $file('Contacts.json');
```